# Converting/Binding JSON data to ASP.NET MVC Model Object

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am pulling some data from an Web API using JQuery Ajax as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:43618/api/Products',
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(data) {
              //some code goes here
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, I would like to bind the pulled data to the MVC ***Model*** in the following view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CosumingWebAPIJQuery.Models.Product>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    }

</table>
```

So how can I convert the pulled JSON *data* into MVC ***Model*** Object and bind it to the View to show the data in a list?? Any Help Please??

Comment: look at knockoutJS

Comment: Is there a reason why you can not call WEB API from MVC action itself?

Comment: You need a client-side binding approach, not a server-side.  The model approach won't work; you can instead not use JSON and instead return HTML from an action method, which is this partial view and then inject the HTML into the UI.  You could also use a client-side control like the Kendo UI ListView (freely available) which I wrote about: https://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/single-page-binding-with-kendo-ui-listview/

Comment: @sam "Is there a reason why you can not call WEB API from MVC action itself?"-No!! Alhamdulillah!! I have done this already but i was trying a little bit different  approach like that..:)

Comment: @Emil I know that also Alhamdulillah (All praise belongs to God)  but  i was trying a little bit different approach like that..:)

Comment: @BrianMains Thanks for valuable suggestion!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot! Your web api is going to return data in JSON format (unless you specify a different accept header). Usually razor code gets executed in the server and html markup will be the output. In your case, you have the json array in client side. you cannot execute razor code there.

One solution (bad solution) is to post the json again to your MVC action method which will then be passed(after converting to your c# class collection) to your partial view and return the view result.

A Better solution is to call an MVC Action method which gets the data and return a partial view result markup. So instead of calling the web api end point, you will call the MVC action method in your web project. If the web api project is part of your MVC web project, you should consider moving the code which returns the data to a common service class method (Which can be called from your web api controller and MVC action method).

Once you get the result from ajax call, which is the HTML markup returned by the partial view, simply udpate the DOM as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the details clarification!! I know and already implemented the the better solution you mentioned!! But I wanted to do so what i have asked here..!!

Comment: You can consider using a client side MVC frameworks like angular where you will pass the data and specify the markup. UI will be updated when you get the data.

Comment: Yes!!..This can be another solution too..Thanks again!!

Comment: There is another option too...That is to use Knockout JS!!